I am getting error while angular version updating (./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed)
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Transform failed with 1 error: C:/Users/WCR/Desktop/WhiteCrow/ATS/ats-crm-frontend/src/app/edit-delete-evaluation/edit-delete-evaluation.component.scss:17:100: ERROR: Unterminated string token at C:\Users\WCR\Desktop\WhiteCrow\ATS\ats-crm-frontend\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:81:18 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
I tried to change the configuration of the tsconfig.ts file angular.json file package.json file for dependency and dev-dependency that are required for the latest version and many more but didn`t work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Actually, I am getting the above error while updating angular version 15 the error was  Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Transform failed with 1 ERROR: Unterminated string token.
